# ランダムフォレスト 、一つ抜き交差検証におけるfeature importanceの出力

Tags: python, python3, scikit-learn

ランダムフォレスト、一つ抜き交差検証を用いて、予測モデルの作成を行っています。
ランダムフォレストでは、feature importanceを出力できますが、一つ抜き交差検証を用いた時の、平均のfeature importanceを出力することは可能なのでしょうか？
可能な場合、どのようなコードを足せばよろしいでしょうか？
現在のコードは以下の通りです。

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score
from sklearn.model_selection import LeaveOneOut
data = np.loadtxt('****.csv', delimiter=',',skiprows=1,dtype=float)
labels = data[:, 0:1]
features = data[:, 1:]
forest=RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=100,random_state=7)
loo=LeaveOneOut()
scores = cross_val_score(forest, features, labels.ravel(), cv=loo)

feature_name= np.loadtxt('feature_name.csv', delimiter=',', dtype=str)
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
def plot_feature_importances(model):
    n_features = features.shape[1] 
    plt.barh(range(n_features), model.feature_importances_, align='center') 
    plt.yticks(np.arange(n_features), feature_name) 
    plt.xlabel('importances') 
    plt.ylabel('features') 
    plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

現状 `cross_val_score()` にて行っている処理を通常のループ処理にて行い、都度 `feature_importances` を配列に格納していくと良いのではないでしょうか

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
#from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score
from sklearn.model_selection import LeaveOneOut
from sklearn.metrics.scorer import accuracy_score

data = np.loadtxt('****.csv', delimiter=',',skiprows=1,dtype=float)

labels = data[:, 0:1].ravel()
features = data[:, 1:]
forest = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=100,random_state=7)
loo = LeaveOneOut()
scores = np.empty([0,])
feature_importances = np.empty([0, features.shape[1]])
for train_idx, valid_idx in loo.split(features):
    forest.fit(features[train_idx], labels[train_idx])
    result = forest.predict(features[valid_idx])
    scores = np.append(scores, accuracy_score(result, labels[valid_idx]))
    feature_importances = np.append(feature_importances, forest.feature_importances_.reshape(1,-1), axis=0)
feature_importances = feature_importances.mean(axis=0)

feature_name= np.loadtxt('feature_name.csv', delimiter=',', dtype=str)

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
n_features = features.shape[1]
plt.barh(range(n_features), feature_importances, align='center')
plt.yticks(np.arange(n_features), feature_name)
plt.xlabel('importances')
plt.ylabel('features')
plt.show()
```